# Como evitar que um texto seja selecionado usando CSS

Tags: html, css

Como fazer para impedir que um texto seja selecionado pelo usuário utilizando uma regra no CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para impedir que um usuário selecione um texto, podemos fazê-lo da seguinte maneira com o código abaixo:

```css
.naoSelecionavel {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;  /* iPhone OS, Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none;    /* Chrome, Safari 3 */
    -khtml-user-select: none;     /* Safari 2 */
    -moz-user-select: none;       /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;        /* IE10+ */
    user-select: none;            /* Possível implementação no futuro */
    /* cursor: default; */
}
```

```html
<p>Texto selecionável</p>
<p class="naoSelecionavel" unselectable="on">Texto <b>não</b> selecionável</p>
```

O atributo `unselectable="on"` no HTML serve para apontar para o Opera, IE9 e versões anteriores

> Referências: [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), [-webkit-touch-callout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout), [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266--webkit-user-select), [unselectable attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)